# How to fixed issue whiule creating cookie in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 my cookie function not create cookie in browser. My code is

```
public function connectWoocommerce(Request $request)
{
    Cookie::queue('site_url', $request->site_url, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    Cookie::queue('key', $request->consumer_key, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    Cookie::queue('secret', $request->consumer_secret, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
    dd($request->all());
}
```

How can solve it thanks.

Comment: why are you doing `dd` ? it doesn't send back a proper response because you've halted the execution. `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` middleware is never called

Answer (score 1):

`\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class` middleware is responsible for setting queued cookies to the response. Make sure to have it in you `$middleware` list.

It will not be called if you terminate the script from anywhere within your controller.

Comment: Thanks. Its my bad now issue is fixed.

Comment: @IrshadKhan glad I could help ; )